# Sharing memory with graphics card does it matters?

Tags: memory, graphics-card, gpu

I use a Graphics card named Bioster HD 6670 DDR5 1 GB And My Ram is 6 GB with 1366 Buzz and In My  Direct Diagnostic Tool i Found that MY ram Shared with my GPU and Showing Approx. Total Memory: 3828 MB Does All That Memory Matters?
Does It comes Any Kind use?

Does It Helps Me for Better Gaming? Or Any kind Of Use?

Comment: Specify your OS architecture, maybe you just can't use all the ram from the beginning, before even use a graphic card.

Answer (score 0):

Using main memory for video memory allows you to play games or CAD that have a lot of textures.  On games that don't require that much video memory the effect is very small.  However, don't expect miracles you still only have a 6670.  If you attempt to load more textures than you have memory your performance will slow down.  There is a very limited set of games that require more than 3gb.